# Копирование текста из буфера обмена в стороннее приложение на андроид по событию (например, встряхнув телефон)

Tags: java, android

*С разработкой под андроид дела никогда не имел, но сейчас понадобилось узнать о возможности реализации замысла, поэтому прошу отнестись с понимаем и смело тыкать носом в документацию и гугл, если я пропустил нужные мне ссылки.*

**Замысел следующий**:
Пользователь заходит в приложение (написанное мной) и копирует оттуда текст. После чего пользователь заходит в любое стороннее приложение (пусть это будет вконтакте), тычет пальцем в поле ввода сообщения и по какому-либо событию (например, пользователь потряс телефон влево-вправо) необходимо автоматически вставить ранее скопированный текст в активное поле ввода (в нашем случае поле для ввода сообщения в диалоге вк)

Я нашел как работать с буфером обмена ([документация](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)) и знаю, что в андроиде есть сервисы, с помощью которых можно отслеживать события по типу потрясли телефон влево-вправо.
**Вопрос в следующем**: могу ли я с помощью этого сервиса (или чего-либо другого) вставить данные из буфера обмена в поле ввода стороннего приложения?
Что касается версии андроида, то интересует 4 и выше.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь это не реализуемо без root прав. Ну а с ними можно попробовать 3й способ из [этой статьи](http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/) (отправка событий нажатия кнопок в /dev/input/eventX устройство)

Comment: а приложения, требующие рут, проходят модерацию в play market?

Comment: @lamo проходят конечно, туда вообще мало что не проходит